# custom log statements using slf4j

Tags: spring, log4j, spring-batch, slf4j, mdc

I need to log statements something like below , in which the log statement consist of some custom values configured. I am using logging in context of spring batch. So i would like to differentiate log statements by the jobs running. Example job1 and job2 are running in parallel so the logs should appear something like ,

```
 2015-08-31 19:14:34 DEBUG Main:23 - [Job1]:testing msg 1
 2015-08-31 19:14:35 DEBUG Main:28 - [Job2]:testing msg 2
2015-08-31 19:14:34 DEBUG Main:23 - [Job2]:testing msg 1
 2015-08-31 19:14:35 DEBUG Main:28 - [Job1]:testing msg 2
2015-08-31 19:14:34 DEBUG Main:23 - [Job1]:testing msg 1
 2015-08-31 19:14:35 DEBUG Main:28 - [Job2]:testing msg 2
```

I checked considering MDC - org.slf4j.MDC  but seems will not help differentiating logs by jobs.

Please help , thanks in advance !

Comment: Why not? MDC works on per-thread basis and you can easily modify your underlying logging mechanism (Logback for example) to log values of MDC. See Logback's docs: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#mdc

Comment: yes i just checked  , thanks a lot

Comment: So at least upvote my comment :)

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1704.  Pull requests are welcome, but it's not a trivial problem to solve at a global scale.